# cannot Open Office 2013 files in Windows 10

Tags: ms-office

I recently updated to Windows 10 and suddenly all the documents that I have been working on cannot be open. I receive this error message:

"Word experienced an error trying to open the file.

Try this suggestions:

*Check file permisions for the document or drive
*Make sure there's sufficient free memory or disk space.
*Open the file with the text recovery converter.
"
I checked the first two, and nothing really changed, I also tried to repair it without any luck. Is there something else that I can do? I would hate to loose my documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, right-click the Word file that you have problems with, and click "Property".

Click "Unblock", when done, click"OK". (Note: a properly-working Word file does not have an "Unblock" button displayed).

Next, you should be able to open this file without further problems. If you encountered this problem in many of your files, you may try the following steps: first, move these files into the same folder, open Word 2010, and then click "File", and click "Options". (For Word 2007, please click "Office" button, and then click "Word options").

Click "Trust Center", and then click "Trust Center Settings".

Next, click "Trusted Locations", and click "Add new location".

Select the folder where you have just moved your files to; when done, click "OK" and then click "OK" again.

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2749199

Comment: Hooray! :) you'e right! It worked!

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried most options people were posting on various forums, but none of the answers worked for me. I then looked a bit more in the "Trust Center Settings" and found the holy grail:

Open Word / Excel / other, create an empty Document, then go to File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Protected View tab and and uncheck the options based on your situation (files from the internet / unsafe locations / Outlook attachment), then click Ok twice.

Go back to the file you were unable to open, and notice that you can now open it.